# Return change set from Outgoing to Unresolved

Tags: eclipse, versioning, rtc, jazz

I checked-in some changes by mistake. Now the changes are in the outgoing changes, but I don't want them to deliver. How can I return them back to the unresolved? If I discard them they vanished from my source code and I lost my work.

Comment: You can check in changes without delivering them.  If you want to reverse the check in, make a copy of your changed source code, discard the changes, then reapply the changes to your source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still discard the change set: see [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/54231/discard-change-set-hey-whered-my-local-project-go).

> By discarding the change set, the changes in it will be reversed. This happens to be the addition of the files once the initial share was performed.

(hence the removal of those files)

> **To avoid this, you can disconnect the project then discard the change set**.

(when you disconnect the project, select the option which don't delete the local files)

> This kind of behaviour is intended as you would want to discard a change and have your local shared content to reflect the same state as your repository workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but this is where I ended up when looking for answer for myself and thought others might come by here and be interested.

In my case, I had made a changeset with my changes, add a related artifact, completed it, and sent it off for review.  It was then pointed out that I had included extra files.  So this worked and was pretty simple:

1. Went into **Related Artifacts** for the changeset and removed the work item so that it would no longer show up in the review.
2. Made a patch of the items in the changeset and saved it to my desktop.  I actually only did the files I wanted since the extraneous files should have been removed in the first place.
3. Discarded the changeset which, as noted, removes all those changes from your workspace.
4. Applied the patch to get the changes back in an unresolved state.  And, in my case, that was only the ones I wanted, not the bonus files which are now gone.  God rest their souls. ;-)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to simply drag & drop files from Outgoing Change Set to Unresolved in the Pending Changes view. Then you can reuse the Change Set for some other changes.

This will work only until you mark the Change Set as Complete.

Comment: When a file is checked-in from unresolved folder, it will reside in outgoing. Hence unresolved folder will not be available unless there is some another unresolved file available.